# проблема с картой в Maui

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, maui

Не могу понять, почему не работает данный код

```
var mapControl = new Mapsui.UI.Maui.MapControl();
mapControl.Map.Layers.Add(Mapsui.Tiling.OpenStreetMap.CreateTileLayer());
mapControl.Map.Home = (n) => n.CenterOnAndZoomTo(new MPoint(54,59), n.Resolutions[10]);
mapControl.Map.Home = n => n.RotationLock = false;
mapFrame.Content = mapControl;
```

как бы должен центр карты поставить на (54,59) и отключить вращение, но не помогает
c#, maui под андроид